# JsonSerializable not returning object after adding a double typed property

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serializable

I generated Item model instance from json using [JsonSerializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and I got this generated code. But it doesn't return an Item after I added a double typed property (price). It worked without it

```dart
Item _$ItemFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Item()
    ..id = json['id'] as int?
    ..kitchenId = json['kitchen_id'] as int?
    ..kitchen = json['kitchen'] == null
        ? null
        : Kitchen.fromJson(json['kitchen'] as Map<String, dynamic>)
    ..name = json['name'] as String?
    ..image = json['image'] as String?
    // This line returns null
    ..price = (json['price'] as num?)?.toDouble();
}
```

Then I tried to fix it and succeed by changing the double parsing

```dart
Item _$ItemFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Item()
    ..id = json['id'] as int?
    ..kitchenId = json['kitchen_id'] as int?
    ..kitchen = json['kitchen'] == null
        ? null
        : Kitchen.fromJson(json['kitchen'] as Map<String, dynamic>)
    ..name = json['name'] as String?
    ..image = json['image'] as String?
    // Changed this line
    ..price = double.parse(json['price']);
}
```

And this is my model

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class Item {
  @JsonKey(name: 'id')
  int? id;

  @JsonKey(name: 'kitchen_id')
  int? kitchenId;

  @JsonKey(name: 'kitchen')
  Kitchen? kitchen;

  @JsonKey(name: 'name')
  String? name;

  @JsonKey(name: 'image')
  String? image;

  @JsonKey(name: 'price')
  double? price;

  Item();

  factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ItemFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ItemToJson(this);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{name: $name}';
  }
}
```

But when I run flutter pub run build_runner build it got resetted back :\ which I need to fix again..

Is there anything I missed? not fixing this code everytime I run build_runner would be great! :) ty

PS: There's no error or anything in my debug console

Comment: can you share the model class?

Comment: do you see any issue/error in logs ? and share your JSON too to get better help

Comment: @AsimJawad I added my model class please take a look ty

Comment: @FaiiziiAwan there's no issue/error in my logs

Comment: can you check if you are receiving the price value from the server?

Comment: Yes I do get the value

Comment: This is one of them

{
"id": 1,
"kitchen_id": 1,
"name": "Item 1",
"created_at": "2021-09-01T04:32:05.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-09-01T04:32:05.000000Z",
"image": "-",
"price": "6500.00"
}